# How to insert a data in mysql as previous and next record

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

How to write SQL in Mysql or Python? I was trying to load on the basis of row_number and how do i bring next value into current row Can you throw some lights on this? 
Input

```
symbol,timestamp,close,open,status,row_number
ABCLTD,2015-01-16,43.25,33.81,Bullish,1
ABCLTD,2015-02-28,29.891,34.22,Bearish,2
ABCLTD,2015-03-05,35.562,34.28,Bullish,3
ABCLTD,2015-03-27,34.23,34.47,Bearish,4
ABCLTD,2015-03-31,35.833,34.53,Bullish,5
ABCLTD,2015-04-30,34.1,34.77,Bearish,6
ABCLTD,2015-05-08,35.029,34.83,Bullish,7
ABCLTD,2015-05-15,33.609,34.87,Bearish,8
ABCLTD,2016-08-12,38.719,36.2,Bullish,9
ABCLTD,2016-10-14,36.233,36.41,Bearish,10
ABCLTD,2016-10-21,38.809,36.45,Bullish,11
ABCLTD,2016-11-18,35.212,36.57,Bearish,12
ABCLTD,2017-01-20,40.81,36.48,Bullish,13
XYZLTD,2018-07-20,1171.31,1172.21,Bearish,1
XYZLTD,2018-08-03,1209.99,1177.21,Bullish,2
```

Expecting Output

```
symbol,timestamp,close,bb_dt,bb_close
ABCLTD,2015-01-16,43.25,2015-02-28,29.891
ABCLTD,2015-03-05,35.562,2015-03-27,34.23
ABCLTD,2015-03-31,35.833,2015-04-30,34.1
ABCLTD,2015-05-08,35.029,2015-05-15,33.609
ABCLTD,2016-08-12,38.719,2016-10-14,36.233
ABCLTD,2016-10-21,38.809,2016-11-18,35.212
ABCLTD,2017-01-20,40.81,Null,Null
XYZLTD,2018-07-20,1171.31,2018-08-03,1209.99
```

Comment: could you add code? It will be helpful for our detecting bug.

Comment: And your primary key

Comment: Seems could use pandas in python to handle this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The row number depends on how the data is retrieved.   Row 1 ordered by date ascending is different to row 1 ordered by descending.

You need to forget row number.  If you want a new record between row 1 and 2 just make sure the value you insert is between the values in the column you order by.